# Insert span next to textbox using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a text box. i want to insert `<Span>Invalid value</span>` next to that text box using Jquery.
Just like when we use validation,It will come next to textbox or else.

Answer (score 16):

Use [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/):

```
$("#myTextbox").after("<span>Invalid value</span>");
```

or [`insertAfter`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/):

```
$('<span>Invalid value</span>').insertAfter('input:text');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input').append('<span>Invalid Value</span>');
```